# Novice: How to do update with id in cakephp2 mysql?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm new to cakephp2 and mysql and I want to create a mysql query to update the data with a id that has been passed in.I'm a very slow learner so I would want some help.

```
$this->User->updateAll(
        array(
                'User.checked_count' => '`User`.`checked_count` + 1',
                'User.modified' => "'" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "'"
        ),
        array(
                'User.username' => $username,
        )
);
```

PS. How to get the results from the query above and use foreach loop? It doesn't work, so Im having a little trouble with it .

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: There is a sample query above. Actually I want to make a condition that if the id is identical, the data's will be updated.And at the same time I want to get the datas from the query as a variable.But since I'm new to cakephp2 and mysql I'm having some trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cakePhp 2.x you can do it like that:

1) Below is simple update using save() function, where you pass id as reference and cake automatically updates the table when id is set else will insert the data in new row:

```
$this->User->id = $Id;
$this->User->save($this->request->data);
```

2) If you want one or more records in a single call to get updated use updateAll() function:

```
$this->User->updateAll(
    array('User.checked_count' => $count),
    array('User.id ' => $userId)
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you know how to add inner join condition to the updateAll method ?

Comment: You are always welcome. You need not to add join conditions during updateAll() instead use saveAssociated().

Comment: You are just awesome! Really helped me!

Comment: Pleasure is mine Buddy. Thanks for the compliment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$this->User->id = $passedId;
$this->User->save($this->data);
```

In above code If `user_id` is present then It update user data other wise it save userData.